# No Route name in VueJS 3 + VueRouter 4

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router

I am using VueJS 3 and Vue Router 4. I want to get the name of the current route using `{{$route.name}}` -  this works so far. But it doesn't return any Route Name, if I'm accessing a route - in this Example I am trying to access /plans/1 - it doesn't return any value. here is my routes-array from the router:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/plans',
        name: 'Learning Plans',
        component: ListPlans
    },
    {
        path: '/plans/:id',
        name: "Leaning Plan: Learn",
        component: ViewPlan,
        props: true
    },
    {
        path: '/plans/:id/edit',
        name: "Edit Learningplan",
        component: EditPlan,
        props: true
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 0):

Vue Router 4.x provides [useRoute()](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#useroute) for that:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()

    onMounted(() => {
      const id = route.params.id
    })
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/getting-current-route-params-composition-api-in-vue-router-4-wujmv)